# How do I get an updated audio track from equalizer in Android?

Tags: java, android, fft

I am trying to alter frequency of an audio track using default android equalizer class. After doing changes on audio I wanted to save updated track to local device.
For equalizer, I am using [demo](https://github.com/bullheadandplato/AndroidEqualizer) on github as a reference.

I am getting the band frequency of an equalizer.
How can I get an updated audio track from an equalizer?
Is FFT algo useful here?

Answer (score 0):

Android equalizer class is for altering  frequency of music that is currently playing, Not for Editing Music File.
For that you need to Use Libraries Like FFmpeg

Comment: Thanks for your answer. FFmpeg library does not alter the frequency of soundtrack like equalizer does. 
I want to change audio frequency using an equalizer and after that download that altered file to the device. I need the best of both the words at moment.

Comment: what actually you needed?, Are you trying to  change the bass ,mids,treble or vocal to create a new file?( Like in some Karaoke maker software ,they reducing mid frequency of music to reduce the voice frequency )